# Get values from relationship Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have a query where I get values from 3 tables, for first 2 I use leftJoin, and is Ok, but for third one I try to get an array of objects, and I am not sure how.
In relationship table a have multiple rows for each ID from People table. HasMany type.

```
$q = Person::leftJoin('registers', 'people.register_id', '=', 'registers.id')
          ->leftJoin('relationships', 'people.id', '=', 'relationships.person_id') //if I comment this it works for first 2 tables
          ->find($id);

return response()->json($q);
```

**Person**

```
public function relationship()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Relationship::class);
}

public function register()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Register::class);
}
```

**Relationship**

```
public function person()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Person::class, 'person_id');
}
```

**Register**

```
public function people(){
    return $this->hasOne(Person::class);
}
```

**UPDATE** -> this works,but is kind of ugly, I think that should be a better way in Laravel

```
$q = Person::leftJoin('registers', 'people.register_id', '=', 'registers.id')
            ->find($id);
$q2 = Person::find($id)->relationship;
return response()->json([
    'values' => $q,
    'relationship' => $q2,
]);
```

Comment: Can you show the models too?

Comment: I updated the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `with` like this:

```php
Person::with(['register', 'relationship'])->find($id);
```